# React app scroll to top only works in firefox

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was having a problem in react where when changing routes, the page would remain in the same spot on the page as the previous page rather then go to the top. I found a solution on here but it only works on firefox. Anyone know how to get this working on chrome and safari?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollToTop = ({ children, location: { pathname } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }, [pathname]);

  return children || null;
};

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

in my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <ScrollToTop>
       <App />
      </ScrollToTop>
    </BrowserRouter> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: did you try using useRef hook ?

Comment: I am using following code it working in all other browsers axcept firefox.
 componentDidMount = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }